# <?php session_start(); ?> did not working well..what should i do

Tags: php, html, dreamweaver

i've try to session above the `<!doctype>`..but when i check the syntax by using PHPtester ..the output was:

"FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected 'is' (T_STRING) on line number 1"

the syntax:

```
 <?php session_start(); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>

<form id="userForm" method="post" action="form-process.php">

<div>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>User Information</legend>
    <div id="errorDiv">
    <?php 
    if(isset($_SESSION['error']) && isset($_SESSION['formAttempt'])){
        unset($_SESSION['formAttempt']);
        print "Errors encountered<br />\n";
        foreach($_SESSION['error'] as $error){
            print $error."<br />\n";
        } //end foreach
    }//end if
    ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: try to remove the space before " <?php session_start(); ?>

Comment: _"unexpected 'is'"_ - Are you sure this is the file it's complaining about?

Comment: @Ace_Gentile ..did not change anything..the error is still same

Comment: @Sai I think you can't use `session` in phptester. It is disabled. The "is" error produces because when you type `session_start()` and execute the code it changes auto to "`Something is wrong_start();`". Plus i don't think any php online will let you use `sessions`

Comment: Ah! PHPtester replaces that line with: `<?php Something is wrong_start(); ?>`. Get a proper IDE that checks the syntax with a linter instead.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about http://phptester.net/? It's ridiculous, it changes checked code.

Try http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ - your code is fine there.

Comment: the result is: " <b>Warning</b>:  session_start() has been disabled for security reasons in <b>" 

what should i do now?

Comment: Remove the space from before opening php tag.